# Dynamic file name doesn't work in rsyslog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs, rsyslog

The filename in rsyslog can be either static or dynamic. The later is useful if you would automatically split messages into different files based on some message criteria. I need split logs depend on IP -like: 10.10.10.10.log
Why doesn't it work? Can I use something different to create it? Maybe python/bash script?

My config file look like this:    [rsyslog v5]

```
#### RULES ####

local6,local5.*                              /var/log/systems/device-all.log

<=15.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog

cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

*.emerg                                                 *

uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

$template DynamicFile,"/var/log/systems/host-%HOSTNAME%.log"

*.*    -?DynamicFile

local6,local5.*                               /var/log/systems/device-all.log
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that first of all you have to set the template as

```
$template DynamicFile,"/var/log/systems/host-%fromhost-ip%.log"
```

because you want separation according to ip.
next I think that the correct value for logging is

```
*.*    ?DynamicFile
```