# rsyslog: append source IP in log file name

Tags: rsyslog, rsyslogd

I have a number of hosts sending logs to `rsyslog` server, and I'd like to distinguish them by adding their IP, i.e. /var/log/10.10.10.1-messages.log, /var/log/10.10.10.2-messages.log and so on. At the moment all messages land in the same log file.

Is it even possible to do so?

I know there exist syslog template files, is this what I should be looking at? I would appreciate some helpful examples, since documentation is quite confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you mentioned in your question, in rsyslog [templates](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/templates.html) are the recommended way to generate dynamic file names.
@meuh has already written a detailed answer to this, see [rsyslog not writing dynamic log file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580460/512694).

Just replace the `%hostname%` message property with `%fromhost-ip%` in the template.

```
template(name="myDynFile" type="string"
    string="/var/log/%fromhost-ip%-messages.log")
```